# SharePoint Calculated Field (DATEIF)

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I'm using SharePoint 2010. Right now I have a calculated column which displays in days the difference between ColumnDate1 and ColumnDate2 as follows:

```
=DATEDIF([ColumnDate1],[ColumnDate2],"d")
```

But sometimes I get an error "#NUM!" when ColumnDate1 is greater than ColumnDate2.

How do I do the following for the same calculated field:

1- Display "NO DATA" when EITHER columns is blank OTHERWISE provide number of days.

2- Display "NOT LATE" when Date1 is greater than Date2, OTHERWISE provide number of days.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK([DATE1]),ISBLANK([DATE2])),"NO DATA",IF(ISERROR(DATEDIF([DATE1],[DATE2],”d”)),”NOT LATE”,DATEDIF([DATE1],[DATE2],”d”)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved my day. I really appreciate it. It works great!!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Action Closed]), "", DATEDIF([ColumnDate1],[ColumnDate2],"d"))
```