# Calculating overdue status in a Sharepoint list using calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

Hoping someone can help as I am relatively new to Sharepoint.  I've created a list to track completion of internal audit activity.  It includes a status column and due date column.  I'm trying to create a calculated column which determines if the item is overdue if the status is not complete.

Can someone please assist?

Thanks

Rachel

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new view and add a filter to it - exclude anything where Status=Completed, since you don't want completed items to show up as overdue.  That covers one of your requirements.

To calculate overdues, you'll need to use something which works ofd the [Today] date.

Here are some posts to existing questions and answers that should help you.  This [existing post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/242534/sharepoint-calculated-field-dateif?rq=1) does something similar.  You might find [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/227394/dynamic-calculated-column-in-sharepoint/227417#227417) of use too.  [This post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/189624/how-to-do-sharepoint-calculated-column-due-date-calculation) also looks useful.

Comment: Is a calculated field going to solve the issue, as the calculation only takes place then the item is updated. Unless some timer job will update the items when they expire?